# css flicker Animation with hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-animations

I want to have a css only animation that fades in and out until hovered when displayed full. I can do both things seperately but not together. The hover element never works. Tried several combinations but here's the 2 seperate parts working:

```css
@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:0.4; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0.4; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0.4; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0.4; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0.4; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0.4; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:0.4; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0.4; }
}
.animate-flicker {
   -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
   -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
   -o-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
}

/* CSS for hover */
.animate {
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.animate:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="animate-flicker animate">
```

Comment: this won't work ... the aniamtion override the value of property being animated ... so nothing else can change this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above you cannot do such thing. As you can read in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/):

> As defined in [[CSS3CASCADE]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/), animations **override all normal rules**

So an idea is to unset the animation on hover:

```css
@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:0.4; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0.4; }
}

.animate-flicker {
    animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
}

/* CSS for hover */
.animate {
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.animate:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  animation:unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate animate-flicker">

</div>
```

Comment: Thansk @Temani Afif I can't up points you as I don't have the ability.